# Shiny R checkboxGroupInput selected all

Tags: r, shiny

I have a checkboxGroupInput in my Shiny app with the following code :

```
checkboxGroupInput("sexe", "Sexe:",
c("Masculin" = "mas","Féminin" = "fem"))
```

My question is how to have them checked when first loaded?

knowing that I've tried selected= c but didn't work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use `selected = c("mas","fem")`

For example

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody( checkboxGroupInput("sexe","Sexe:", 
                                    choices = c("Masculin" = "mas", "Femenin" = "fem"),
                                    selected = c("mas","fem")))
)

server <- function(input, output){

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Also may be better : create `choise_list=list("Masculin" = "mas", "Femenin" = "fem")` and then use `choices = choise_list,
                                    selected = choise_list`    ( may be better add to answer)